# A concrete example where Redux solves a real problem

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

It is mentioned in this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/why-use-redux-reasons-with-clear-examples-d21bffd5835/)

> Now imagine what happens when a state has to be shared between
> components that are far apart in the component tree. The state has to
> be passed from one component to another until it gets to where it is
> needed.

Could someone please explain this with a code example?

Comment: I'd recommend you to join to https://www.reactiflux.com/ (there's a discord server) and check  this https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/ and this https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world/src. Furthermore, if you are gonna start working with Redux, I recommend you to use redux toolkit https://redux-toolkit.js.org/.

Answer (score 2):

This question for me is very interesting despite it has negative votes, because it opens again the discussion of **why Redux and not React Context for creating a global store?**. The answer is very simple: because Redux helps to implement a loosely coupled architecture.

So a concrete example of which real problem solves Redux is that the state is not bounded to a component that is what makes React Context. So this concept can be applied developing a market place of plugins (that is a bunch of micro-frontends) built with React where we can have the Plugin A and Plugin B.

And to have access to this market place, we need to be authenticated from the Core Application for enabling access to the selected plugin. So in this case the authentication system must be in Redux making it transversal for all the plugins (microfrontends).

So to understand that, we can have this folder structure:

```
|-core-app        //Shell app (Where all microfrontends can be visualized)
   |-App.tsx
   |-etc...
|-plugin-a        //Microfrontend A
   |-App.tsx
   |-etc...
|-plugin-b        //Microfrontend B
   |-App.tsx
   |-etc...
|-store           //Contains shell app and microfrontends root states
   |-store.ts
|-reducers        //Contains shell app and microfrontends reducers 
   |-authReducer.ts
   |-etc...
```

It's a possible scenario where we can have shared reducers for the shell app and the different micro-frontends. Now imagine that we need to be authenticated to have access to one of these microfrontends, so we will need the credentials data got from the shell app to be passed to the selected microfrontend. So an easy way to achieve that is with Redux.

Now imagine that the whole project is a multi-repo: so plugin-a, plugin-b and the core app has its own repo each one, **and even** the store with the reducers folder, can be both an isolated repository acting as a single source of truth where the application states must be coded.

So we will have here 4 repositories to prevent the project to be a big mono-repo.

It's an example of a loosely coupled architecture in frontend, where we can split a big project (a market place) in sub-projects which it's own repo and even a single repo for the transversal state.

I hope these thoughts can be useful and give you a starting point to the answer you are looking for.